# What are the errors in this function from a Microsoft interview question?

Tags: c, string

I was asked this question in the MS written walkin-interview:

Find errors in the program below which is supposed to return a new string with `\n` appended to it.

```
char* AddnewlinetoString(char *s)
{
  char buffer[1024];
  strcpy(buffer,s);
  buffer[strlen(s)-1] = '\n';
  return buffer;
}
```

I'd tried to code on myself and was able to get it working by making buffer variable global and having `buffer[strlen(s)] = '\n'`. But did not know there were many other bugs in it.

Comment: So which ones did you see?

Comment: Is that code from windows 95 ?

Comment: All that because windows has no `strdup`, that is ?-)

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: let's see your corrected version that uses strdup then.

Comment: This is almost a definitive example of why string handling in C is a terrible mess!  I wonder how many fewer security issues the world would have faced if `std::string` was always used instead...

Comment: @AshleysBrain: I guess that in an interview, the question is interesting to see if the candidate knows about the problems and issues of this kind of code, and how to code correctly to avoid them.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: you can write completely idiotic code in any language. All this code shows is that the author is an idiot.

Comment: @R: Languages with built-in string handling make a whole family of errors impossible.

Comment: I think you mean built-in dynamic memory allocation, not built-in string handling. And some of us would consider that a huge negative, not a positive feature. Would you like your pacemaker to hit OOM conditions due to memory fragmentation? :-)

Comment: @R: No, I'm not referring to dynamic memory allocation. I'm referring to strings being a first class citizen of the language with natural operators and a sane representation, instead of a null terminated array of chars. Dynamic memory allocation prevents an even bigger family of errors, but at the cost you mention.

Comment: Let's see people from Java schools answer this one :)

Comment: why this question has been closed? Its very much related to programming.

Comment: Hard to see how this is not programming related. Voting to reopen.

Comment: There are two kinds of programmers - the ones that will think through a problem to see all of the relevant details, and the ones who will just keep trying stuff until it seems to work. Guess which group you fall into? Guess which kind Microsoft is looking for?

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged C++. If someone writes this kind in crap in C++ they need to actually step back and learn C++.

Comment: I see a story about an interview you had.  Where's the question?

Answer (score 55):

I can see a few:

> Length of input string not checked.

What if the `strlen(s) > 1023`? You can fit a string of length at most `1023` in buffer.

> Overwriting the last char with `\n`

You are overwriting last char with newline. Your `\n` should go where `\0` used to be and you need to add a new `\0` after `\n`

> Variable buffer is local to function and you are returning its address.

Memory for buffer is allocated on stack and once the function returns, that memory is freed.

I would do:

```
char* AddnewlinetoString(char *s) {

  size_t buffLen = strlen(s) + 2; // +1 for '\n' +1 for '\0'
  char *buffer = malloc(buffLen); 
  if(!buffer) {
   fprintf(stderr,"Error allocting\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  strcpy(buffer,s);
  buffer[buffLen-2] = '\n';
  buffer[buffLen-1] = 0;
  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough, the `\0` is probably still there (if the first error doesn't trip it). Look again, is the `\0` overwritten?

Comment: 2.  `strlen` doesn't include the terminator in the length.  So at most, the code just replaces the last char of the string with a newline, but the nul will remain if it already was there.

Comment: "Memory for buffer is allocated on stack and once the function returns, that memory is freed."  It's a long, long time since I did any c++  but I thought that as long as the memory was referenced by a pointer (and not explicitly deallocated) it would remain allocated ( or is that me getting java in my c++)

Comment: @TygerKrash: The stack holds values local to the current function. Once the function returns, your pointer is pointing to garbage, i.e. you don't know what's there (e.g. the next function's local variables can overwrite the region your pointer points to).

Comment: +1 - I would rephrase to say "once the function returns, the memory is out of scope" - allocated and freed are loaded terms in the context of malloc etc.  Distinguish more clearly between heap and stack memory usage.

Comment: This will leak memory if used like: `str = AddNewlineToString(str);`

Comment: @sje397: That's not a problem with the function, provided it is properly documented that the caller owns the returned buffer, and is responsible for freeing it appropriately.  The only alternative is to work with a global buffer, which has much more severe issues.  *edit: Given that you're stuck with a C-like interface, of course.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: lack of docs (or comments) could be considered a problem. Another alternative would be to free the input pointer (yeah, not good). Anyway my point is that it was doomed from the moment the signature was written ;)

Comment: 'Twould not be a bad idea to make the function argument const.

Comment: This crashes if you pass null as the argument.

Comment: Noone has mentioned yet that the original function fails if you pass it an empty string (it accesses s-1 in that case)

Comment: @Tony: nothing wrong with that. It will also crash (or worse) if you pass `(char*)rand()` or any other invalid pointer. Why should NULL be treated specially?

Answer (score 8):

1. there's no limit in strcpy, better use strncpy.
2. you are copying to static buffer and returning pointer.

Comment: Surely that's not a static buffer?

Comment: Instead of `strncpy` one should make sure the buffer is of suitable size. Exactly what good is it doing if you get the input truncated, rather than having newline appended? This should take care of both issues.

Comment: If available, strlcpy would be better.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a C++ version without errors:

```
std::string AddnewlinetoString(std::string const& s)
{
    return s + "\n";
}
```

And here is how I would probably write that in C++0x:

```
std::string AddnewlinetoString(std::string s)
{
    return std::move(s += "\n");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question though :)

Comment: True, but... I don't think the point of these exercises is to come up with a better version *per se*, but to understand the intricacies of the errors.  Consider it a test of debugging your mediocre colleagues' work, rather than a test of writing new code yourself.

Comment: The question is tagged C++, that would imply this is a potential correct answer!

Comment: @Fred - Better to pass by ref to const.  What comments would you make about exception handling?  This is an interview q remember - not making errors is only half the battle. I agree w Filip that you would also have to answer the question as stated, in an interview situation.  Perhaps this is for C work.

Comment: @Steve: I added your suggested reference to const version, but I still like the [pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) version better, especially with the `std::move` edited in :)

Comment: Shouldn't the C++0x version return an rvalue reference?  What's the point of using `move` if you return by value?  [I admit, I'm an rvalue references noob, so maybe I'm wrong]

Comment: @James: No, returning rvalue references is almost always wrong, because it can lead to a subtle problem with dangling rvalue references at client side. In this case, there is another obvious problem: `s` is destroyed when the function returns, so it would be a very bad idea to return an rvalue reference to it. The job of `std::move` is to *enable* moving by treating the argument as an rvalue, thus allowing the move constructor do have its way with `s` when leaving the function. Without the `std::move`, the copy constructor would initialize the return value, because `s += "\n"` is an lvalue.

Comment: @Fred:  That's what I thought (concerning making the return type an rvalue reference).  Now I understand why you move the string to return it, though.  Thanks.

Comment: @Fred @James: I'm *pretty* sure C++0x says that variables bound by a functions scope are treated as rvalues during a return. That is, you can do `s += '\n'; return s;` and that last line will be the same as `return std::move(s);`. Note if you do: `return s += '\n';`, you do need the explicit move since, unless the function is inlined, the compiler can't be sure `&s == &(s += '\n')`. This is all a big "I think".

Comment: So in conclusion, I think the best way would be, for both C++03 and C++0x, `std::string AddnewlinetoString(std::string s){ s += '\n'; return s; }` Considering the parameter: in C++03, when working with an lvalue you'd make a copy anyway, so nothing is lost. And a compiler will elision the copy of an rvalue. In C++0x, you again make the needed copy, but are guaranteed to move-construct the parameter when it's given an rvalue. So nothing lost there. And then you do your manipulation, then return the copy. In C++03, you get NRVO and in C++0x, you get an implicit move return. (Again, I think.)

Comment: @GMan: I had an email discussion with Doug Gregor on that matter, and he said that returning variables defined inside the function body are implicitly moved, but function arguments must be explicitly moved, because the function has no control over how they are created or some technical reason similar to that.

Comment: Oh, and +1 then since I agree with your C++ variations, with that knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

I would also add that the name of the method should stick to pattern and each word should start with capital letter:

```
char* AddNewlineToString(char *s)
{
}
```

ps. Thanks Konrad, I have changed the method name as you have suggested

Comment: But “newline” (as in “newline character”, not “new line of text”) is **one** word. The name should be `AddNewlineToString`.

Answer (score 4):

3 things

```
   int len = strlen(s);
   char* buffer = (char*) malloc (len + 2);   // 1
   strcpy(buffer,s);
   buffer[len] = '\n';           // 2 
   buffer[len+1] = '\0';         // 3
   return buffer;
```

Edit: Based on comments

Comment: Calling `strlen()` three times instead of using a temporary might lead to disappointing results.

Comment: @aeh: strlen doesn't count the terminating '\0', so actually it replaces the last char before the '\0' and fails for empty strings that contain only the termination.

Comment: @aeh: your answer contains a bug.  You simply return a new string with the last character of s replaced by `\n`.  len is one character too small.

Comment: You don't check for `s` being `NULL` and for `malloc()` to fail.

Comment: they would also like `char* AddnewlinetoString(const char *s)`

Comment: @Georg: there is no legitimate reason to check for `s` being NULL. Would you also like to check it against the billions of other invalid pointer values?

Comment: @R..: Right, that should be covered by documentation and possibly an assert.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a corrected version (community wiki incase I missed anything)

```
// caller must free() returned buffer string!
char* AddnewlinetoString(char *s)
{
  size_t len;
  char * buffer;

  if (s == NULL)
    s = "";

  len = strlen(s);
  buffer = malloc(len+2);
  if (buffer == NULL)
    abort();
  strcpy(buffer,s);
  buffer[len] = '\n';
  buffer[len+1] = 0;
  return buffer;
}
```

As tony mentions, s may be a valid address but still be a malformed c-string, with no null bytes.  The function could end up reading until it causes a segfault, or some other horrible thing.  While this is still idiomatic C, most folks prefer counted strings (rather than null terminated ones.)

```
// caller must free() returned buffer string!
char* AddnewlinetoStringN(char *s, size_t len)
{
  char * buffer;

  if (s == NULL)
    s = "";

  buffer = malloc(len+1); // only add 1 byte, since there's no need for the nul
  if (buffer == NULL)
    abort();
  strncpy(buffer,s,len);
  buffer[len] = '\n';
  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: You're one character short on your malloc I think - you need space for the \n and the terminating NULL, so len+2.

Comment: i'd personally check for s being null as the first thing I did. This is a common problem with string args and if you dont check for it, it will assert.

Comment: @Tony: Not a bad call, how do you like this version?

Comment: there is just one more little hole.... if you pass in a string without a terminating zero, but to nail that down you would need to assume maximum lengths for strings.

Comment: Is this the level of question you need to pass to work for Microsoft these days? To work for Google they ask you how to move a mountain.

Comment: * This seems to be the best answer by far yet has one of the lowest scores!

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with this code is that it's vulnerable to a [stack buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) exploit. It's a classic example.

Basically, the input char* can be made longer than 1024 bytes; these extra bytes will then overwrite the stack, allowing an attacker to modify the function return pointer to point to their malicious code. Your program will then unwittingly execute the malicious code.

Microsoft might be expected to care a good deal about these kinds of exploits, since the Code Red Worm famously used a stack buffer overflow to attack hundreds of thousands of computers running IIS web server software in 2001.

Answer (score 1):

No need for return pointer. Change the incoming pointer.

`int len = strlen(s);
s[len] = '\n';
s[len + 1] = '\0';`

Comment: It will not work, first assignment replaces terminating zero, and second strlen will return invalid result. You should swap them.

Comment: That need not work always. What if the input is a `string literal` or a char array which has `len-1` char already stuffed in so that when you access index `len+1` you are stepping past the allocated memory.

Comment: @codaddict: if it was a string literal, someone is ignoring the signature - it isn't a `const` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it should be

```
std::string AddNewlineToString(const std::string& s) // pass by const reference
{
    return s + '\n'; // and let optimizer optimize memory allocations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For C-style strings it may be

```
char* // we want return a mutable string? OK
AddNewlineToString(
  const char* s // We don't need to change the original string, so it's const.
)
{
     const size_t MAX_SIZE = 1024; // if it's a mutable string,
                                   // it should have a known capacity.

     size_t len = strlen(s);
     if(len + sizeof("\n") // To avoid the magic number "2".
         > MAX_SIZE)
         return NULL; // We don't know what to do with this situation,
                      // the user will check the result and make a decision -
                      // to log, raise exception, exit(), etc.

     // static                    // We want a thread-safe result
     char* buf = new char[1024];  // so we allocate memory in the heap
                                  // and it's C-language-string but not C language :)

     memcpy(buf, s, len); // Copy terminating zero, and rewrite it later? NO.
     memcpy(buf + len, "\n", sizeof("\n")); // The compiler will do it in one action like
        // *(int16_t*)(buf + len) = *(int16_t*)"\n";
        // rather than two assignments.

     return buf;
}
```

Comment: Your use of `sizeof("\n")` was initially unclear; I'm not sure avoiding a "magic number" is worth it in this case.

Comment: @Gman: for example if we want provide a C-compatible interface. With heap allocated memory, we should provide only one function to delete any heap-allocated memory, but for allocated-by-string memory we can't easily do it.

Comment: @Abyx: Pretty strange to justify something with "It might be used in C." I wouldn't assume that in any of my code, and such an assumption is certainly outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @GMan: not "in C" but "C-compatible". It means "in C#, F#, Python (ctypes), Haskell and lots of other languages". You can't export function with std::string result from DLL, and use this function in module written in another language (or module compiled by another C++ compiler too). It's Microsoft's question, it's about Windows, not cross-platform programming with gcc only.

Comment: @Abyx: Fair, but I reiterate my point: In C++, write C++. If you happen to need to interface with another language *then* change the code to do so. I think justifying your answers poor resource management with "It could be used by another language" is poor, since nothing says anything about such a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can be made very simple using strdup:

`char* AddnewlinetoString(char *s) {

  char *buffer = strdup(s);

  buffer[strlen(s)-1] = '\n';

  return buffer;

}`

Answer (score -1):

Here goes a simpler way:

```
char* AddnewlinetoString(char *s)
{
  char buffer[strlen(s)+1];
  snprintf(buffer,strlen(s),"%s\n",s);
  return buffer;
}
```